# В каких случая нужно использова char а в каких wchar_t

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

Возник вопрос между использованием `char` и `wchar_t`. Сначала я создал программу

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* ptr = new char[MAX_PATH];
    memset(ptr, 0, MAX_PATH);
    if(SHGetFolderPathA(0, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, 0, 0, ptr) == S_OK)
    {
        lstrcatA(ptr, "\\FolderName");
        if(CreateDirectoryA(ptr, 0))
        {
            printf("ok\n");
        }
    }
    delete[] ptr;
    system("pause");
}
```

И запустил её на Windows 10 полностью английской версии. Всё сработало отлично и папка `FolderName` как и ожидалось создалась. Затем я подумал что если запустить эту программу на ОС в которой имя пользователя будет на другом языке(не английском) то программа не сработает и нужно будет использовать `wchar_t`. Но когда я запустил программу на ОС в который имя пользователя было `Валерий` программа сработала и папка создалась. Отсюда у меня возник вопрос в каких случая нужно использовать `wchar_t` если и с `char` всё работает?

Comment: *"всё работает"* - а вы попробуйте с именем, содержащим сразу и латиницу и кириллицу и иероглифы какие-нибудь. Практически всегда следует использовать API, принимающее wchar_t. Собственно у многих новых API варианта -A нет. А еще не следует закладываться на ограничение `MAX_PATH`.

Comment: если хотите функции, которые заканчиваются на A - используйте char, хотите функции на W - используйте wchar_t. А хотите нормально - используйте TCHAR и другие дефайны и тогда апи функции будут без суффикса A/W и все (почти всегда) будет работать. Стоит заметить, что внутри библиотек/ядра используются W функции. А для A функций используется перекодирование.

Comment: Забавно, что весь C++ здесь ограничивается использованием new/delete.

Comment: где то так. Но бывает и хуже. Но вот в с++ должен быть тип "системная строка". что то с интерфейсом обычного std::string, но что бы его легко можно было передать внутрь сишных функций, которые возвращают строку параметром.

Answer (score 1):

`whar_t` в Windows API когда-то были UCS-2, теперь они UTF-16. Это всегда Unicode.

`char` могут соотвествовать какой-либо кодировке. С относительно недавних пор (2019) [эта кодировка может быть UTF-8](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page), ранее это всегда была не-Unicode кодировка.

`TCHAR` -- позволяет условную компиляцию с `char` или `wchar_t`.

Windows внутри переводит из `char` в `wchar_t`, некоторые функции есть только для `wchar_t`, весь COM использует `wchar_t`.

Зачем тогда иметь дело с `char`, если с `wchar_t` имеем Unicode, а с `char` - проблемы с кодировками? Возможные причины:

- Когда-то были системы Windows 9x, там `wchar_t` функции не были реализованы. Системы уже никем не поддерживаются, но остался код, который всё ещё не перенесен на `wchar_t`
- `char` используется в других ОС, т.е. для универсальности.
- `char` используется в библиотеках, даже в самом C++ `std::exception::what` возвращает char

Comment: `whar_t в Windows API когда-то были UCS-2, теперь они UTF-16.` - а есть какие то подтверждения? насколько я знаю, они продолжают использовать суррогатные пары.

Comment: @KoVadim, "Unicode-enabled functions are described in Conventions for Function Prototypes. These functions use UTF-16 (wide character) encoding, which is the most common encoding of Unicode and the one used for native Unicode encoding on Windows operating systems." -- отсюда https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode?redirectedfrom=MSDN . Что переход на UTF-16 случился в Windows 2000, источник не найду, но так написано в Википедии

Comment: а потом буквально на пару строк ниже `and UTF-16 code points in the range U+D800 through U+DFFF are used to form surrogate pairs` - суррогатные пары.  Там все ещё сложнее. USC-2 - это просто устаревшее и не рекомендуемое http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-11

Comment: Для систем Windows 9x был Microsoft Layer for Unicode.